# ER diagram to SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

[image]

In a test, I was asked for the query to

"show the Net Effective Rent (NER) for all future tenants. This query should be structured to allow further analysis by Province, City, Property, Unit Type and NER/ft2. Make any necessary assumptions".

For which I wrote:

```
select T.rent*T.leaseterm+M.Charge_Amt*M.duration as NER
from tenant T 
join property P on T.property_ID = P.property_ID
join moveincharges M on M.tenant_ID = T.tenant_ID
join unit U on T.unit_ID = U.unit_ID
where T.status = 2;
```

I was told that's not the best answer. Was I right? How could I improve the solution?

*NO Data set nor expected result was given for testing the correctness of the solution. The information provided should be sufficient to develop a solution. Think it is a take-home interview test.

Comment: Please provide sample data, expected results and actual results.

Comment: FYI:  To be safe for multiple levels of calculation you should use parentheses around each part of your formula because sometimes the order of operations can change your results (not always but always better to be safe than sorry) and its easier to read/understand your intentions

Comment: *"allow further analysis by Province, City, Property, Unit Type and NER/ft2."* Where are these columns?

Comment: Sql Server 2018... must have missed that version, lol.

Comment: @sTTu: So did Microsoft.

Comment: Am I the only one who wants to know why move in charges has a duration in months? And even more so why it can be indefinite?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' I think you are right. I should probably show some IDs as well.

Comment: @Meruemu but as the person attempting to solve the problem your first step should be to setup some sample data (yourself) and determine the results you expect, so that you know when your query works. Otherwise how do you know you're solved the problem? You would then be able to answer this question yourself.

Comment: It will certainly make your life easier... and is the only way you can verify if someone elses answer is correct.

Comment: @Meruemu how do you define best? Again, if you provide sample data (in DDL+DML), and expected results, you make it much easier for anyone here to assist.

Comment: You can argue all you like - but my suggestions will not only help you to learn and answer the question yourself, but help others to help you as well. Up to you. The more you put in the more you will get out. And if you don't know what is right or best, then how will you know someone has provided you with the correct answer? Over and out.

Comment: Two attractive characteristics in a job candidate: taking advice and problem solving skills.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't see any use of Property or Unit table in the calculation. So, I have removed those from the query.

```
select T.rent * T.leaseterm + M.Charge_Amt * M.duration as NER
from tenant T 
inner join moveincharges M on M.tenant_ID = T.tenant_ID
where T.status = 2;
```

You might get provice,city,property and unit_type wise average ner.

```
select  P.provice,p.city,p.property,u.unit_type,avg( T.rent*T.leaseterm+M.Charge_Amt*M.duration) as NER
from tenant T 
left join property P on T.property_ID = P.property_ID
inner join moveincharges M on M.tenant_ID = T.tenant_ID
left join unit U on T.unit_ID = U.unit_ID
where T.status = 2;
group by P.provice,p.city,p.property,u.unit_type
```

Comment: It's better to use ``Left join`` on property and unit because maybe one of them will referenced in tenant table.

Comment: "This query should be structured to allow further analysis by Province, City, Property, Unit Type and NER/ft2. " is the reason I kept other tables in my query.Yes probably left join is better.

Comment: If this answer helped to solve your problem please accept it.